# Submit ALL rows in data table with text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatable that has a series of text inputs in each table row, but I need to submit data from all pages as I am using a fairly large data set and not using paging isn't an option.

I have seen a few fixes for this regarding checkbox inputs but I didnt want to add a checkbox on each row to click if the row had been edited I just want to submit all data that had been entered.

Comment: How are the inputs setup and bound to the table data? Can you not make individual requests when change is made to each one?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery events such as **'change ,keyup ,onblur'** to trigger  for the series of text boxes or check boxes ,provide code snippet to clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example in the DataTable website.
https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html